# Nodejs verify jwt token from .net failed

Tags: c#, node.js, jwt

I create token from .net by this C# code (with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt):

```
var keybytes = Convert.FromBase64String("MYCUSTOMCODELONGMOD4NEEDBEZE");
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(

new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(keybytes),
SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature,
SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);
var nbf = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-100);
var exp = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(100);
var payload = new JwtPayload(null, "", new List<Claim>(), nbf, exp);
var user = new Dictionary<string, object>();
user.Add("userId", "1");

payload.Add("user", user);
payload.Add("success", true);
var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(new JwtHeader(signingCredentials), payload);
var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var resultToken = jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(jwtToken);
```

I send the `resultToken` to nodejs and verify it (with jsonwebtoken library) with below code:

```
var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken');

var result = jwt.verify(
  resultToken,
  new Buffer('MYCUSTOMCODELONGMOD4NEEDBEZE').toString('base64'),
  { algorithms: ['HS256'] },
  function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
    console.log('decode token failed with error: '+ JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }
);
```

I got the error: invalid signature. The resultToken content:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0OTQ4MTMxMTUsIm5iZiI6MTQ3NzUzMzExNSwidXNlciI6eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxIn0sInN1Y2Nlc3MiOnRydWV9.4bjYyIUFMouz-ctFyxXkJ_QcJJQofCEFffUuazWFjGw
```

I have debug it on [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) with above signature (`MYCUSTOMCODELONGMOD4NEEDBEZE`) and secret base64 encoded checked, it's ok.

I have tried a signature without base64 encoded by chaging `keybytes` in C# code:

```
var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MYCUSTOMCODELONGMOD4NEEDBEZE");
```

And it verified successfully in nodejs. So i think the issue comes from my nodejs code when verify a base64 encoded signature. Did i miss some options when verify token or somethings?

Comment: Please check this [https://runkit.com/589803649a353c0015f87d57/589803649a353c0015f87d58/branches/master](https://runkit.com/589803649a353c0015f87d57/589803649a353c0015f87d58/branches/master) and its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what you did but this snippet is working for me with the token you provided above.

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple')

var secret = new Buffer('MYCUSTOMCODELONGMOD4NEEDBEZE').toString('base64')
var token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0OTQ4MTMxMTUsIm5iZiI6MTQ3NzUzMzExNSwidXNlciI6eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxIn0sInN1Y2Nlc3MiOnRydWV9.4bjYyIUFMouz-ctFyxXkJ_QcJJQofCEFffUuazWFjGw'

var decoded = jwt.decode(token, secret)
console.log(decoded)
```

Output:

```
❯ node jwt.js
{ exp: 1494813115,
  nbf: 1477533115,
  user: { userId: '1' },
  success: true }
```

Using jsonwebtoken library

```
// var jwt = require('jwt-simple')

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = Buffer.from('MYCUSTOMCODELONGMOD4NEEDBEZE', 'base64')
var token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0OTQ4MTMxMTUsIm5iZiI6MTQ3NzUzMzExNSwidXNlciI6eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxIn0sInN1Y2Nlc3MiOnRydWV9.4bjYyIUFMouz-ctFyxXkJ_QcJJQofCEFffUuazWFjGw'

jwt.verify(token, secret, { algorithms: ['HS256'] }, function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(decoded)    
    }  
})
```

Again still working fine.

The only difference i can see is the secret.

Comment: Sorry for my un-clear about library in my question. I'm using  jsonwebtoken (https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) which is listed on jwt.io.I will use jwt-simple like your snippet but i still curious what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @khoa_chung_89 updated. jsonwebtoken works for me as well. probably the secret is what's wrong.

Comment: It works now :) thanks for your help. Not sure why i cannot create the buffer in your way (it may due to my nodejs version). I have to create the buffer and encode base64:  var secret = new Buffer("MYCUSTOMCODELONGMOD4NEEDBEZE", "base64");

Comment: @khoa_chung_89 I'm using node 7. Probably API changes.